# Python. Выполнение условия при совпадении одного из значений в файле

Tags: python, парсер, файлы, условия

помогите реализовать подобие игнор-листа для бота:
Есть список, скажем, .txt с id пользователей в игнор-листе. Необходимо, чтобы выполнялась подобная команда:

```
if message.from_id != *все id пользователей в игнор-списке*:
    send.message('hello')
else:
    continue
```

Рассмотрю также варианты с таблицами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого существует оператор `in`.

```
>>> 5 in [1, 8, 4, 5]
True
>>> 6 in [1, 8, 4, 5]
False
>>> 5 not in [1, 8, 4, 5]
False
```

В вашем случае:

```
if message.from_id not in [123, 456, 789]:
    send.message('hello')
else:
    continue
```

Если значения в текстовом файле, одно значение на строку, то сначала нужно прочитать файл, и перевезти текст в каждой строке в тот формат, который нужен вам. К примеру если значения, это числа, то:

```
with open('ignore.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

ids = map(int, lines)

...

if message.from_id not in ids:
    send.message('hello')
else:
    continue
```

Comment: В `ids = map(lines, int)` выдает ошибку  `ids = map(lines, int)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Comment: @SkyKing: Сорри. См. исправленный код.

Comment: теперь ошибки нет, но в ids возвращает `<map object at 0x00000181EC3B40A0>`

Comment: @SkyKing: Разумеется. Оператор `in` может использоваться со списками, но также и с итераторами.

Comment: если точнее, то `in` работает везде, где определен `__iter__` и `__next__`